# Access parts of Constructor that is in a vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

So lets say I have a vector of a type which contains an int, and 2 strings. 
What would be the best way to pull ints or strings from my vector of my custom type, so I could compare them other objects?

I tried pushing back one vector into another of just an STL type, but I know that

```
vector<sometype> v;
vector<string> v2;
for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); ++i;)
{
    v2.push_back(v[i]);
}
```

won't work, and I'm not really sure how else to do it.

Comment: `v2.push_back(v[i].stringField1)` will work, but I seriously doubt it solves the real X in this XY problem.

Comment: You should be implementing an overload of `operator ==`. That way the caller won't have to manually extract the data members. Show us what your class looks like and an example of how you want to compare objects of this type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide sometype code I wrote example code on my own.

```
class sometype {
  int a;
  std::string b;
  std::string c;

public:    
  friend bool operator==(const sometype& lhs, const sometype& rhs);
};

bool operator==(const sometype& lhs, const sometype& rhs) {
  if (lhs.a == rhs.a &&
      lhs.b.compare(rhs.b) == 0 &&
      lhs.c.compare(rhs.c) == 0) {

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: That got me on the right path of thinking, and I managed to create another class that worked for my purposes.